# How to make a simple cross-platform webbrowser with Python?

Tags: python, winapi, cross-platform, webkit

The http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/ looks great but it seems to be running on linux only.

Does anybody know if there is something similar but cross-platform?

If not what can be the alternatives to make with Python a simple web-browser that can run on Windows, MAC os and linux?

Thanks in advance

Update: Does anybody has some information about [wxWebKit](http://wxwebkit.wxcommunity.com/index.php?n=Main.HomePage) ?

Comment: What makes you believe that PyWebKitGtk is Linux-only?

Comment: Some articles found on the web but maybe I didn't understand correctly. However it has to be compiled and it doesn't seem to be that easy. Please answer if you have info about using PyWebKitGtk on Win32 or MAC

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Qt (which has Python bindings with [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) or [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/)) offers [Webkit](http://webkit.org/) (the same engine as Safari). Making a simple cross-platform browser is [trivially implemented](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/webkit-pyqt-rendering-web-pages/) with this.

To show how easy this really is (example taken from the link):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com"))
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind modifying code in an open-source project, you can attempt making [Grail](http://grail.sourceforge.net/) run in a modern version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to this question asked 3 years ago, I would like to mention 
[Chromium Embdedded Framework](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/). It worths a try.